# Why is my Sorting script works inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Hi helpful contributors,

I have a response google sheet that has a set of datarange with different type of data values (screenshot) as below. Col2 Timestamp values are auto-generated upon user input in gform. I moved it as col2 (default is in col1) because I want to put the Quote ID as primary key col. Quote ID values are auto-generated based on google script that is triggered upon submission of gform:-
gresponse sheet with inconsistent sort[image]

I supposed we would have the data range autosort by timestamp (and I need it significantly to sort by timestamp) but this is not happening consistently with mine. I already tried the below codes but still not working consistently too. But when I sort it manually in the sheet using the feature Filter to choose Timestamp column and then sort A->Z, it works fine. But that won't be effective for my requirements

Method 1 :

```
// this resulted as in the screenshot.

SortRange = "A2:AC";
SortOrder = [{column:2, ascending: true}];
function multiSortColumns(){
  var range = msheet.getRange(SortRange);
  range.sort(SortOrder);
}
```

Method 2 :

```
// some sorted, some not but still wrong and not ascending order.

SortRange = 2,1,sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn();
SortOrder = [{column:2, ascending: true}];
function multiSortColumns(){
   var range = sheet.getRange(SortRange);
   range.sort(SortOrder);
}
```

Method 3

```
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().sort(2);
// this doesn't sort by specific column we want and it includes sorting the header.
```

Please help to correct my code. Tqvm in advance.

Comment: Are you running this function on formSubmit trigger? Why are the timestamps messed up in the first place? Usually the form submits data to the destination sheet in a chronological order.

Comment: @ziganotschka OP manually sorted other columns maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Potential Issues:

- The first two methods in your question don't seem to define the
  `sheet` object.
- Also I am not even sure if you execute
  `multiSortColumns` at all.
- The third method will also sort the header as well.
- Another potential issue would be when using:

  ```
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ```

  The latter considers the active sheet which can be any of the **selected** sheets in the spreadsheet file.

Instead I would advice you to use:

```
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
```

assuming the name of the sheet you want to sort is `Form Responses 1`

---

### Solution:

Here is a modified version of your second method which makes sure that everything is executed when you execute `myFunction()`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // not recommended
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); // recommended
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 2, ascending: true});   
}
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works, @Marios! Thanks! Sorry earlier I didn't mention the main function where I call the sort function. I thought that was not significant to highlight the issue because before this that function (Method 1) works just fine as I was testing it multiple times before using it since July. I noticed it suddenly stop working when I tested to enter the non-gmail addresses and that has affected the other records with gmail address eversince. kinda weird. I hope ur script will work forever though. Thx!